# How to stop Python program execution in IDLE

Tags: python, matplotlib, tkinter, break, python-idle

I have a python script that uses `plt.show()` as it's last instruction. When it runs, IDLE just hangs after the last instruction. I get the image but I don't get the prompt back.

On other scripts I typically use `ctrl-c` to break the program (sometimes doesn't work immediately) but how do I get the prompt back with the `plt.show()`? `Ctrl-c` doesn't work...

Are there other ways to stop the program?

This is IDLE on Windows, if it makes any difference.

Comment: some options here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1219394/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I have seen this problem with IDLE and matplotlib when using them on Windows. I don't know the exact cause, but Ctrl-c a couple times has typically worked for me. If that doesn't work for you, you can use the normal interpreter instead of write your plot directly to a file instead of the screen.

This is one of those (plentiful) times when IDLE doesn't behave like a normal Python script or interpreter session. Because of this, I usually avoid IDLE.

Comment: Unfortunately, the options on Windows aren't great. I use the interactive interpreter directly (despite cmd.exe not being all that nice) and call Python from gvim to run scripts. Any number of editors and IDEs can call Python directly, and many of them are listed on http://wiki.python.org/moin/IntegratedDevelopmentEnvironments . iPython can suffer from some of the same problems of IDLE, but I suspect it goes out of its way to make matplotlib work (I never use it myself, so I can't promise so).

Comment: When one presses ^C in IDLE's Shell, the Shell sends a message to the execution process to raise interrupt there.  Most of the time when that fails, it it would have failed if one had hit ^C while running directly under Python.  There are reasons completely independent of IDLE why Python cannot always gracefully stop and emit a >>> prompt upon a ^C interrupt signal.

Answer (score 7):

Ctrl+F6
(Restart shell)

or Shell->Restart Shell

Answer (score 2):

When you use `plt.show()`, the python subprocess enters the GUI toolkit's event loop and blocks until the event loop exits. When it exits, you get the prompt back.

If you are using the TkAgg backend, you'll need to move your mouse over a figure after you press Ctrl+C. That will cause the event loop to stop. (Tkinter has its quirks)

Alternatively, [IdleX](http://idlex.sourceforge.net) offers Matplotlib support with IDLE using the EventLoop.py extension. You can display and interact with figures without using `plt.show()`. Just be sure to set `plt.interactive(True)` before generating figures.

Answer (score 2):

I had same issue in Canopy Python Editor, and I was able to interrupt python session with `CTRL+.` ("dot" button). Hope that helps, or they probably do things in a similar ways