# How to stop python idle editor?

Tags: python-idle

I ran a program using the python idle.

Now, it process stopped and it appeared to be hanged.

From Task Manager, there is no CPU usage.

I pressed Control+C but cannot stop the process and save the result.

What should I do?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Similar to this. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2460401/how-to-stop-python-program-execution-in-idle

Answer (score 1):

If Interrupt, cntl-C, does not top execution after possibly a few presses and a wait of at least a few seconds, there is probably no way to access results.  One will have to kill the process (and wipe the memory).  If Python is running in a console, close the window.  In IDLE, Shell => Restart Shell closes the execution process but leaves the GUI process running so you can try again without restarting IDLE.

Comment: Thank you for your comment, Terry.